# Spark Streaming - Kafka- createStream - RDD to Data Frame

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We have a stream of data coming through a Kafka topic. I read that using Spark Streaming.

```
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(l_sparkcontext, Seconds(30))
  val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "xxxx.xx.xx.com:2181", "new-spark-streaming-group", Map("event_log" -> 10))
```

This works nicely. What i would like is to write this a Parquet file by assigning columns to the stream data. Thus i do the following

```
kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  if (rdd.count() == 0 ) {
    println("No new SKU's received in this time interval " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
  }
  else {
    println("No of SKUs received " + rdd.count())
    rdd.map(record => {
      record._2
    }).toDF("customer_id","sku","type","event","control_group","event_date").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("parquet").save(outputPath)
```

However this gives an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): _1
New column names (6): customer_id, sku, type, event, control_group, event_date
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.toDF(DataFrame.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameHolder.toDF(DataFrameHolder.scala:36)
    at kafka_receive_messages$$anonfun$main$1.apply(kafka_receive_messages.scala:77)
    at kafka_receive_messages$$anonfun$main$1.apply(kafka_receive_messages.scala:69)
```

What is the mistake that i am making please. Should we split in the map ? If we do that then we are not getting to convert it to toDF("..columns..")

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Bala

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for stopping by. I have sorted this out. It was a coding issue. For those who want to do this in the future, please change the else part as below

```
kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  if (rdd.count() == 0 ) {
    println("No new SKU's received in this time interval " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
  }
  else {
    println("No of SKUs received " + rdd.count())
    rdd.map(record => ( record._2).split(","))
  }.map(r => (r(0).replace(Quote,"").toInt,r(1).replace(Quote,"").toInt,r(2),r(3),r(4),r(5))).toDF("customer_id","sku","type","event","control_group","event_date").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("parquet").save(outputPath)
  })
```

Thanks again

Bala